# Selecting a table is shutting down my MySQL server (Error 2013)

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

In my Moodle database, everytime I select the mdl_certificate table, the MySQL server goes down. I thought it could be a problem with the PHPMyAdmin, but I installed the MySQL Workbench and the same still happens.

So I tried the console. The problem persists. I got two prints:

[image: Using other tables, everything is ok.]

[image: The lost of connection]

I've never seen this. How can I solve it?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
This is the log around the time the error was showed:

```
130411  8:51:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130411  8:51:20 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130411  8:51:20  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
130411  8:51:20  InnoDB: Operating system error number 1392 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\prestashopprod
InnoDB: File operation call: 'readdir_next_file'.
InnoDB: Error: os_file_readdir_next_file() returned -1 in
InnoDB: directory .\prestashopprod
InnoDB: Crash recovery may have failed for some .ibd files!
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 4793, file name .\mysql-bin.000062
130411  8:51:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130411  8:51:34 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 795429719
130411  8:51:34 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
130411  8:51:34 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130411  8:51:34 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130411  8:51:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130411  8:51:34 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.20-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Could you put your mdl_certificate table's schema please ?

Comment: I can't. Even I trying to fetch the columns the server goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was drop the tables and re-create them. Luckly, they were empty.